# Java web application - retrieving client windows credential

Tags: java, ntlm

I have a java web application(hosted in Linux) which speaks to a document management system which is a .NET based system via rest services. By default SSO Kerberos authentication is used in document system and for the same we are passing SSO Token to identify the user who accesses our application via web browser. This works fine and the document system is able to identify the user and allows user to upload document.

However we have a problem when a user who belongs to a different domain/AD tries to access the application. This is due to the external trust level between the environment document service is hosted and user environment. The document mgmt system supports NTLM authentication to handle this scenario and we were told that we need to pass credential object in the request. It appears there are easy ways for .NET client to extract user credential using CredentialCache object but I am struggling to find equivalent in Java.

I am trying to find out a way to pull the users windows credential so that I can set in the credentials object before i send the request to document system. Our application is SSO enabled, hence we dont want the user to explicitly pass his windows credential.